# Open different activities on each listview click

Tags: android, listview

I am having problem setting OnClickListener to my listview.
I want to open different activities when different listview item is being clicked. But i am not able to get it done. Any help is Appreciated.

My Activity

```
public class ListviewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ListView listview;


int number = 1;


private int image;
private String title;
private String description;
private String price;


public int[] IMAGE = {R.drawable.white, R.drawable.white, R.drawable.white, R.drawable.white, R.drawable.white, R.drawable.white, R.drawable.white, R.drawable.white};
public String[] TITLE = {"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H"};
public String[] DESCRIPTION = {"CEO", "CEO", "CEO", "CEO", "CEO", "CEO","CEO","CEO"};


private ArrayList<BeanClassForListView> beanClassArrayList;
private listViewAdapter listViewAdapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.contact_listview);

    listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    beanClassArrayList = new ArrayList<BeanClassForListView>();


    for (int i = 0; i < TITLE.length; i++) {

        BeanClassForListView beanClass = new BeanClassForListView(IMAGE[i], TITLE[i], DESCRIPTION[i]);
        beanClassArrayList.add(beanClass);

    }
    listViewAdapter = new listViewAdapter(ListviewActivity.this, beanClassArrayList);
    listview.setAdapter(listViewAdapter);

}
}
```

My Listview Adapter

```
public class listViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context context;
private ArrayList<BeanClassForListView> beanClassArrayList;


public listViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<BeanClassForListView> beanClassArrayList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.beanClassArrayList = beanClassArrayList;


}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return beanClassArrayList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return beanClassArrayList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHoder viewHoder;
    if (convertView == null) {

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview, parent, false);

        viewHoder = new ViewHoder();


        viewHoder.banar1 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.banar1);
        viewHoder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        viewHoder.description = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.description);

        convertView.setTag(viewHoder);

    } else {

        viewHoder = (ViewHoder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    //NavigationItems rowItem = (NavigationItems) getItem(position);

    BeanClassForListView beanClass = (BeanClassForListView) getItem(position);

    viewHoder.title.setText(beanClass.getTitle());
    viewHoder.description.setText(beanClass.getDescription());

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), beanClass.getImage());
    viewHoder.banar1.setImageBitmap(getRoundedCornerBitmap(bitmap, 20));


//       viewHoder.plus.setImageResource(beanClass.getImage());
//        viewHoder.min.setImageResource(beanClass.getImage());
    //viewHoder.no.setText(beanClass.getNo());


    return convertView;

}


private class ViewHoder{

    ImageView banar1;
    TextView title;
    TextView description;


}

public static Bitmap getRoundedCornerBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int pixels) {
    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap
            .getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

    final int color = 0xff424242;
    final Paint paint = new Paint();
    final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
    final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);
    final float roundPx = pixels;

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    paint.setColor(color);
    canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paint);

    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);

    return output;
}}
```

BeanClassForListView

```
public class BeanClassForListView {

private int image;
private  String title;
private String description;


public BeanClassForListView(int image, String title, String description) {
    this.image = image;
    this.title = title;
    this.description = description;

}

public int getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(int image) {
    this.image = image;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use OnItemClickListener for it.

```
 lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                    long id) {
             Intent intent = null;
              switch(position){
                      case 0 :
                       intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
                       break;
                      case 1 :
                       intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this,ThirdActivity.class);
                       break;
.......
}

startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Getting error Error:(80, 31) error: variable intent might not have been initialized

Comment: @NiravJain That's a regular Java error, this answer does what you need. Anyways... `Intent intent = null;`

Comment: Though, the condition for starting an activity probably depends on the data within the list, not just the position

Comment: listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                    long id) 
I modified the code according to yours and now android studio doesn't throw error however nothing happens when i click the listview item

Comment: Share your full class code so I can give you what is the issue?

Comment: I have checked your code all the code of java classes are code but issue in your listview.xml(listview row xml). Which is not coded optimized way some layouts are none usable. I have commented your code and put one textview and tested it was working.

Answer (score 0):

Do this in your Activity:

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){ 
  @Override 
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?>adapter,View v, int position){ 
  ItemClicked item = adapter.getItemAtPosition(position);
  //Use switch case to call different activities for different cases
  Intent intent = new Intent(Activity.this,destinationActivity.class);
  startActivity(intent); 
} });
```

Comment: @NiravJain This answer isn't meant to be copied literally. `ItemClicked` is obviously not a class in your code, it should be the class that's displayed as part of the adapter

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you set an `OnClickListener` for your `View` though. Inside of your `ListAdapter`'s `getView()`, you should do

```
View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

if(v != null) {
    v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(YourContext, ActivityToStart.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    });
}
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: can you please help me. Full source code. http://www95.zippyshare.com/v/tiCz8E1P/file.html

Answer (score 0):

```
convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview, parent, false);
```

below it,add

```
convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (position == 1){
            getActivity().startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,secondActivity.class));
        }else if (position == 2){
            getActivity().startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,secondActivity.class));
        }else if (position == 3){
            getActivity().startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,secondActivity.class));
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: try this,           getActivity.startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,secondActivity.class));

Comment: getActivity is a method. Please add parentheses accordingly

Comment: thats right !!    getActivity().startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,secondActivity.class));

Comment: Though, `setOnItemClickListener` is the more correct way to do this